# vue data not showing sometimes ! but work sometime ! why?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am using laravel 6.0 and use vue components.After npm run dev I refresh the page and name(data on component) not showing. but after I refreshing page few times It will show up and some time again not showing the data (name) coming from request.

ExampleComponent.vue

```
 <h5>{{name}}</h5>

 data() {
     return {
        name: ''
     }
 },
 mounted() {
      axios.get('/api/user')
         .then(response => {
             console.log(response);
             this.name = response.data.name;
      });
 },
```

Console log show the data and but sometime it not show in vue component. but some time works fine.In both time console log data shows correctly.

[console log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMKPd.png)

I have already tried with

```
mounted() {
let self = this;
  axios.get('/api/user')
     .then(response => {
         console.log(response);
         self.name = response.data.name;
  });
 },
```

But nothing changed on situations.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle or sandbox environment that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Are you waiting long enough for `self.name = response.data.name;` to execute before refreshing? a `GET` request via `axios` is not always instant.

Comment: You don't have to declare self and point to this when using arrow function. ```this``` inside axios will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's better you can use `created()` instead of `mounted()`. `created()` fetch data when the component is created. Please have a look - [click-here](https://lavalite.org/blog/created-and-mountedin-vuejs)